# how to get the dataset of a rendered line in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am working on line charts and new to D3.js. I have a chart which selects data from multiple datasets and creates multiple lines, now that lines are rendered for each such dataset, I want to get data for each point in the line when a line is selected(as in when hovering over lines). so, I am trying to get the dataset (which was used to create the line) when the line is selected. (Is there a way to assign id to paths such that when any point is selected in that path it should return the path id using which I can retrieve the dataset which was used for creating that path?)

Comment: You should be able to apply the `on` event to the `paths` to trigger on hover: `d3.selectAll("path").on("mouseover", f1);` and then `function f1(d){...}` will have d as the hovered object, and from there it should be easy to get the data.